# How take photo and reduce image file dimension

Tags: android, image, compression, photo, image-size

in my android app i've implemented a method for taking a photo and save it in a folder specified by me.

I would like to automatically resize the image (or compress it) to reduce the file dimension under the 1MB, obviously before saving it.

Which is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html   , it has good examples of how to keep your filesize down on photos

Comment: i saw the link,
but explain how resample the photo to load in the app, i need to have small picture when i  safe the image from the camera, i need to have a smalla picture saved in the memory.

Comment: Are you using an Intent or your own surfaceview? If you're using and Intent it's impossible, then you first have to receive the image and then alter it. I know that you can do setMaxFileSize when recording video but I don't know if that's possible with photos since you're dependent on the cameras MP, size etc. What's the reason you can't take the image, reduce the filesize and save it again?

Comment: Yes i'm using an intent!
I did not know that this could not be immediately reduce,
i want to do before saving to optimize the response time of the app and the use of space on the SD.

However, I tried the tutorial that I've reported it and it worked, thank you!